# 'Might' is the subjunctive inflection of 'may'; was there ever a subjunctive inflection of 'must'?

Tags: single-word-requests, modal-verbs, subjunctive-mood, archaicisms, obscure-terms

I acknowledge that there is no subjunctive mood in English. However, there are variants of some words that we might regard as subjunctive variants. For example, 
'might' is the, if you will, subjunctive inflection of 'may'.

Was there ever a subjunctive inflection of 'must'?

Comment: _Must_, being formed from an old preterite like _might, should, could,_ and _would_ (note the final -t/d suffix), is already as subjunctive as it can get. The present form is archaic and exists only in fixed formulas ("So mote it be").

Comment: @JohnLawler. Okay, so then *may* is to *might* as *mote* is to *must*, but not as *must* is to *mote*. Is that true?

Comment: @JohnLawler. You've answered the question. Perhaps you could paste that as an answer so we can close the question?

Comment: I thought "may" itself is already a subjunctive. Similarly "will" originally was, and hence also used to describe the future which is generally contingent on uncertain things. I also don't know why you say there is no subjunctive mood in English (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive). Just for example, "The law requires that a contract be in writing.".

Comment: And "may/will/shall/can" are present subjunctives while "might/would/should/could" are past subjunctives.

Answer (score 1):

> Must, being formed from an old preterite like might, should, could,
>   and would (note the final -t/d suffix), is already as subjunctive as
>   it can get. The present form is archaic and exists only in fixed
>   formulas [("So mote it be")](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mote). –  John Lawler Apr 13 at 18:31

(Citation added)

> @JohnLawler. You've answered the question. Perhaps you could paste
>   that as an answer so we can close the question? –  Hal Apr 13 at 18:54

Mister Chairman! 
I motion to close.